# libcouchbase error: Authentication failed

Tags: couchbase

I've been doing a tutorial of CLI access on couchbase and I faced this error. Now, I'm using the sample bucket of couchbase, 'travel-sample' and I've tried this:

```
$cbc cat airline_10 -U couchbase://127.0.0.1

libcouchbase error: Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination (0x2)
```

airline_10 is one of the document's id in the travel-sample and
I've already googled with that error so I found out that I have to make sure to be set up the password of a bucket.

The bucket, travel-sample, doesn't have a password.

Is there anyone who can help me? plz let me know how to figure out this problem :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Oooops, sorry guys. I should add the bucket name at the end of URI like this: $cbc cat airline_10 -U couchbase://127.0.0.1/travel-sample

but still when I create a document with cbc create, it would occur the same error a thing like above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the bucket you want use, it is a bug in the documentation. Try this:

`cbc cat airline_10 -U couchbase://localhost/travel-sample`

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details about the issue when you run the command with `-vvvvv` to increase verbosity (less `-v` -- less verbose)

If you are using Couchbase Server 5 release, you need to create new user or specify administrator credentials, because empty passwords and implicit usernames (as name of the bucket) are not allowed. To specify username, use `--user, -u` switch, for password `--password, -P`.

More information you can get in the [`cbc(1)`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-c-client-2.7.6/md_doc_cbc.html) manpage

Comment: I will use -v later :) Thanks! Btw you mean 4.5 or above version? Ok, I'll keep in mind the fact I have to specify things !

Comment: I mean 5 and above

Comment: The latest version is 4.x though.